# Uploading App - Where is the Configuration Field in XCode 4?

Tags: iphone, configuration, distribution, provisioning, uploading

I'm trying to upload my first app to App Store. I'm following the instructions in the **iOS Provision Portal**. The problem is that all the instructions and screen shots are still relevant to XCode previous version...

I'm stuck in **Distribution** tab in the section called **Building your Application with XCode for Distribution** in instruction #4 (see screen shot attached).

[image: Building your Application with XCode for Distribution - #4]

It says "**In the Target Info window, select the ‘Build’ tab and set the ‘Configuration’ to ‘Distribution’**".

Where do I find this ***Configuration*** field in **XCode 4**?

Answer (score 0):

In left view listing files etc in xcode, go to the top and click the project name. You'll see target etc show up on right.

Xcode 4 is different from Xcode 3 so you'll have to navigate and check it out.

Update: The configuration option has been converted into schemes. You can create schemes for debug, distribution etc and once the scheme is selected you can configure that target as well.

[Info on schemes](http://pilky.me/view/17)

Comment: Gary, thanks for the answer. I already found the app Target. if you look at the screen shot from the iOS Provision Portal that I included in my original note, you'll see that they are directing to a field called "Configuration". I couldn't find this specific field

Comment: That option has been converted to schemes. Click on scheme in top bar and you can manage schemes from there. Use this link for more information http://pilky.me/view/17